Canon LBP6000B does not print
I've been using Linux for some time now, my base is Ubuntu 24.04.1. I need to put drivers on my Canon LBP6000B printer, but when I connect the printer to my laptop and press “Print”, nothing happens. I've been looking for various solutions on the forums for about a week, but haven't found an answer. Would be glad to get some help from your side.

does this ubuntu handbook article answer your question?

This question is similar to: How to install Canon LBP2900 / 2900B printer on Ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
